# Automatically transfering a range of data from one sheet to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data (Zone) **from sheet1** and paste it **to sheet2** using a button. After clicking the button, the original data on sheet1 will be deleted after being transferred to sheet2.

I keep getting

> Error 13: Type Mismatch

on line `Zone = Range("A2:A20").Value`.

Can I use this code to transfer multiple rows of data, and if so what is the mistake I'm making with my code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Zone As Integer
    Worksheets("sheet1").Select
    Zone = Range("A2:A20").Value
    Worksheets("sheet2").Select
    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B1").Select

    If Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B1").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
        Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Select
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Zone
    Worksheets("sheet1").Select
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: The way you are setting Zone is creating an array most likely. Since you are not outputting the array, you are getting an error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply a Range to an Integer

From

```
Dim Zone As Integer
Zone = Range("A2:A20").Value
```

To

```
Dim Zone As Range
Set Zone = Range("A2:A20")
```

Comment: The original line is how you would go about setting a 2D array in a single statement. The bottom portion is how you would set a range which seems to be your aim. Either way, your action statements will also need to be adjusted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Notice the ask is accomplished without any use of `.Select`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim LR As Long, cRange As Range '(copy Range)
LR = ws2.Range("B" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Set cRange = ws1.Range("A1:A20")

If ws2.Range("B2") <> "" Then
    ws2.Range("B" & LR).Resize(cRange.Rows.Count, cRange.Columns.Count).Value = cRange.Value
    ws1.Range("A2").ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I ran your code I get **Error 424: Object Required** once I get to `If ws.Range("B2") <> "" Then` line. Am I making an error on my end when I'm inserting the code?

Comment: Updated - please try again

Comment: ws.Range("B2").Value

Comment: Thank you so much for following up, and helping me out. However, the code provided isn't working. The values aren't being transferred to sheet2. I tried correcting ("Sheet1") and ("Sheet2") to ("sheet1") and ("sheet2"), but still no luck. Again though thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: This works for me. Do you have any values in range `A1:A20` on Sheet1? Do you have any values on `Column B` on Sheet2? Is B2 blank?